# How to deal with a biased feature in Machine Learning (date)

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a model that predicts the lifespan of a horse. The dataset has samples from 1980 to 2019 and among the features there is one called **birth_date**, labeled with the lifespan in years for each horse. The problem is that knowing that a horse usually live between 20 and 30 years, if we look from 1980 to 1990 we have the full list of horses and their lifespans, but from 2000 to 2019 we see only samples of horses that were born and died withing this time span but not the ones that are currently living, therefore the **birh_date** is a biased feature.

Is there a way to use the **birh_date** feature without having to worry about the biased data, or some technique to minimize his effects on the final predictions?

Comment: It might be slightly more appropriate to ask for help at the [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) regarding this issue.